# Can't reach env from React Component in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I have a Next.js project. I have created `.env` file and using enviroments from this file in server.js file. But when I want to reach these enviroments from component, I can't access. What should I do?

This is .env file:

```
SERVER_PORT=3000
DOMAIN=127.0.0.1
DATABASE=dburl
```

This is server.js file:

```
require('dotenv/config')

const port = process.env.SERVER_PORT || 3000
server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if(err) throw err
      console.log(`Server listen on http://127.0.0.1:${port}`)
    })
```

This is any component of react:

```
axios
    .get(`http://${process.env.DOMAIN}/api/improve-language`)
    .then(res => {
      ...
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      console.log(err)
    })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nextjs components can't access env.local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69421139/nextjs-components-cant-access-env-local-variables)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NextJS environment variables aren't working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63257107/nextjs-environment-variables-arent-working)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables) if you want to use the env variables in the browser, they must be named with prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Comment: I've changed name of `.env` file to `.env.local` and changed enviroment name from `DOMAIN` to `NEXT_PUBLIC_DOMAIN`. But still not working...